# Access Dropbox account for users without creating an app for every user account

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a Dropbox account and I have created/ registered an app in App Console.
Then using the App key/ App secret for the created app and using OAuth process I have stored my access token in my Asp.Net project database table.I could upload/ download/ delete files from my Dropbox account.There are many users in the project and they have individual Dropbox account.

Now my requirement is to store access token for every user in my database without creating an app in Dropbox App Console(https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) for every user Dropbox account.

Is there any way to fulfill my requirement?

Comment: [Cross-linking with https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205760643-Dropbox-account-for-users-without-creating-an-app-for-every-user-account on the Dropbox API forum.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, your app should only have one app key and secret. Think of the app key is identifying **your app**, and not any particular user.

The **access token** is what identifies a user, and you'll need one of those for each user of the app. When a new user starts using your app, you'll need to take them through the OAuth flow to get an access token for that user.

Take a look at Dropbox's [OAuth guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide) to see if that helps.

Comment: In your app? That's entirely up to you... based on your mention of ASP.NET, I assume you're building a web app, so this would presumably be part of your user signup/login?

Comment: I was confused for some reason. Correctly said... thanks